# How do I apply a tax to an invoice?

Tags: xero-api

I want to apply a tax (say 14%) to an entire invoice. Applying it on per-lineitem basis would also be okay.

Based on Xero's description of a Tax Rates, it looks like I should create a Tax Rate of 14%, and associate the line items with that rate. But I'm only permitted to associate the line items with a Tax Type.

How do I set the taxes on an invoice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tax rate for your required percentage; a tax type is generated and returned in the response from this request. You can then use this tax type in each line item on your invoice.